# Ubuntu LIVE on USB - All Storage not Available

Tags: partitioning, usb

I have Ubuntu LIVE installed on a USB storage drive.  In GParted it shows that sda is my hard drive and sdb is my USB drive.  The only partition on sdb is /dev/sdb1 which has a size of 14.56 GB (of which 12.48 is Unused).  I just figured that this total space would be available for me to use.  However, when I open file manager it shows that I only have 109.8 MB of free space.

Can someone explain to me why this is ?
Is there a way to for me to be able to use the total unused space ?

Thanks,
Darrell

Answer (score 1):

What did you use to make the USB Live drive?

Startup Disk Creator creates a ISO9660 partition that is read only.

Unetbootin will create a drive with a read/write partition that can support persistence using a casper-rw file of maximum 4GB.

mkusb will create a drive with ISO9660 OS partition, ext4 persistence partition and NTFS storage partition that Windows can see and use.

I would recommend mkusb:   http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf

Comment: Hi... I used UnetBootin but I did not create the persistence.  I will give mkusb a try and let you know what happens.  Thanks for your help !!!